# document.write a json vector to a table

Tags: html, json, angularjs

Firstly I get orders:

```
app.controller('customersController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("http://18ff2f50.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/tests/Customers_JSON.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
        console.log("debug",response);
       $scope.orders = response;
      });
```

In an order I have a detail:

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'">
    ....
    <div class="col right">
      <button ng-click="viewOrderDetails(x.detail)">订单详情</button>
    </div>
```

I have a json vector (which is returned from the server) stored in "detail" like this:

```
"detail":
"{\"4\":
    {\"num\":2,
     \"id\":\"4\",
     \"name\":\"\\u86cb\\u7092\\u996d\",
     \"price\":\"10.00\",\"total\":20},
   \"6\":
     {\"num\":1,
      \"id\":\"6\",
      \"name\":\"\\u626c\\u5dde\\u7092\\u996d\",
      \"price\":\"10.00\",\"total\":\"10.00\"},
    \"5\":
      {\"num\":1,
       \"id\":\"5\",
       \"name\":\"\\u51b0\\u6dc7\\u51cc\",
       \"price\":\"8.00\",\"total\":\"8.00\"
}}"


$scope.viewOrderDetails = function viewOrderDetails(detail) {
            var newWin = open('orderdetails.html','windowName','height=300,width=300');
            newWin.document.write('html to write...\n');
            newWin.document.write(detail);

            newWin.document.write('<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="window.close()">');
        }
```

I want it displayed in a new window like this:
[image]

how should I do the document.write? Thanks.

Comment: What is detail, can you add part of the code you cut off?

Comment: @dfsq, thanks for your concerns, please see updated post.

Comment: have you tried  `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: @DontGiveUp, I don't know how to write in document.write ways....

Comment: @IsaacLi I think it will consume a lot of code. Why don't you use jQuery plugin ?

Comment: @IsaacLi I have updated my code to use document.write() way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $compile service to compile template to write into new window:

```
app.controller('customersController', function($scope, $http, $compile) {

    $http.get("order.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.x = response;
    });

    $scope.viewOrderDetails = function viewOrderDetails(order) {

        var newWin = open('', 'windowName', 'height=300,width=300');

        var template = 
            '<div>' +
                '<table>' + 
                    '<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in order">' + 
                        '<td>{{value.name}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{value.id}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{value.price}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{value.total}}</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</table>' + 
                '<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="window.close()">' +
            '</div>';

        $scope.order = order;
        var table = $compile(template)($scope);

        newWin.document.body.appendChild(table[0]);
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pMCClUYMkpeyMiFwphrj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I got another problem: my  json vector's format has been changed: "extra \ was added", how to solve that? thanks.

Comment: Try to explain better, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I've updated my original post, please check that out, my json vector has been changed.

Comment: I recommend you to use proper JSON structure. What you have now makes little sense - don't serialize inner object into string, JSON is already serialized object.

Comment: Do you mean the detail now is not a json structure but a string? I get the "detail" from the server, it's the server returning me a string. I can't control the server's behavior, so what can I do to parse the string? Thanks.

Comment: You should ask server-side devs to return proper data. You can of course parse it yourself (with JSON.parse) twice but in this case both server-side and client side becomes crappy. Data source must be fixed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look the code below, If you don't want to use jQuery, and want to use document.write() way. Use this code in your orderdetails.html file

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <script>
            var detail = window.opener.detail;
            for(key in detail) {
                document.write("<tr><td>"+ detail[key]["num"] +"</td><td>"+ detail[key]["name"] +"</td><td>"+ detail[key]["price"] +"</td><td>"+ detail[key]["total"] +"</td></tr>");
            }
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know if it is not working.

Comment: Thanks, I got another problem: my  json vector's format has been changed: "extra \ was added", how to solve that? thanks.

Comment: So your former data has been changed to string ?

Comment: I've updated the post, my json vector has been changed.

Comment: @IsaacLi Try using this function `replace(/\\"/gi, '')` in order to get rid of `\"` in your data. and then use `eval()` to make your string become an Object which you can use in the previous code.

Comment: I tried like this: obj=order.replace(/\\"/gi, '');
obj=eval(obj);  but it didn't work. Am I wrong in using it?

Comment: No problem friend 没问题！